# jQuery plugin not working on jquery hash loaded page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have my php page loaded with hash, and the page is with jquery plugin dataTable,
plugin is loaded but not working, if i reload page, then it is working. ..but not working with jquery ajax loaded with hash.
PHP page contain following script loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="lib/datatables/css/vpad.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's error console? You really need to learn how to do basic debugging.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok do some thing like this
place this code in your **ajax loaded page** ....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        } );
</script>
```

**this is because data table not working in live loaded pages**. there are other many ways to do this but this is simple and easy 
100% works

Comment: @AndreaTurri Ooh man actully problem is not the document ready . problem is that datagrid is not working on live elements so thats why i bind it on live result ....